# Using MDBootstrap with Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

For days I've been trying to use MDBootstrap with my Laravel project. I'm especially trying to create MDBootstrap Datatables. I've successfully installed MDB with npm and yarn but I'm getting a jquery error `ReferenceError: $` at the `$(document)` in my web browser's console when trying to access the index.blade.html page. This index page is being extended from the app.blade.html, which includes the scripts that [Bootstrap's webpage over MDB Data Tables](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/datatables/#docsTabsOverview) requires. I downloaded MBD directly and tested out their datatables and the index.html worked flawlessly. I'm still very new to Laravel (and PHP) so any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

app.blade.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
    <!-- MDB icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('node_modules/img/mdb-favicon.ico')}}" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('node_modules/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('node_modules/css/mdb.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('node_modules/css/style.css')}}">
    <!-- MDBootstrap Datatables  -->
    <link href="{{asset('node_modules/css/addons/datatables2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Laravel Project</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('node_modules/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('node_modules/js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('node_modules/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('node_modules/js/mdb.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Your custom scripts (optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- MDBootstrap Datatables  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('node_modules/js/addons/datatables2.min.js')}}"></script>

    <script>
        // Material Design example
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample').DataTable();
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper').find('label').each(function () {
                $(this).parent().append($(this).children());
            });
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').find('input').each(function () {
                const $this = $(this);
                $this.attr("placeholder", "Search");
                $this.removeClass('form-control-sm');
            });
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_length').addClass('d-flex flex-row');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').addClass('md-form');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper select').removeClass('custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper select').addClass('mdb-select');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .mdb-select').materialSelect();
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').find('label').remove();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.blade.html

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>User Table</h1>

    @if(count($users) > 0)
        <table id="dtMaterialDesignExample" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-sm">ID
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Name
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Occupation
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Location
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Salary
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->occupation}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->location}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->salary}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endif
@endsection
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);
        return view('users.index',['users'=>$users);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have painfully discovered, using MDBootstrap with Laravel can be a little finicky at times, but I got my datatable functioning properly and with the correct styling after I was able to correctly reference the required js files (using Laravel Mix). With the styling, I neglected using app.sass as at the time I was unaware of its functionality. However, there were/are some times after including other scripts when mdb.min.js will still throw me the "TypeError: "exports" is read-only" error which I resolve by deleting the js files from the public folder and recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed them using npm, then you need to compile all your assets by first running

```
npm install
```

and after that

```
npm run dev
```

after that you will need to include your files as such

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">

    <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Laravel Project</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    @yield('content')
    </div>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        // Material Design example
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample').DataTable();
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper').find('label').each(function () {
                $(this).parent().append($(this).children());
            });
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').find('input').each(function () {
                const $this = $(this);
                $this.attr("placeholder", "Search");
                $this.removeClass('form-control-sm');
            });
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_length').addClass('d-flex flex-row');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').addClass('md-form');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper select').removeClass('custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper select').addClass('mdb-select');
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .mdb-select').materialSelect();
            $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').find('label').remove();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

also check your controller for a typo on this line

```
 return view('users.index',['users'=>$users);
```

which should be

```
 return view('users.index',['users'=>$users]);
```

in addition to the above, go to resources/bootstrap.php and include the following

```
try{
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap')
//to get the exact name for the bootstrap, go to package.json and copy out the //name for mdbootstrap exactly


require('name_for_mdboostrap')
    }catch(e){}
```

then run npm run dev again to recompile

Comment: Okay, I did the first commands and included js/app.js. Do I still need to include the other scripts that Bootstrap says is required for their datatables? After your suggestions I am receiving "TypeError: "exports" is read-only" error from app.js in my web browser's console.

Comment: npm install will do all those inclusion, the npm run dev will compile it for you, you do not need any other included files

Comment: can you tell which of the included file is having the error?

Comment: The particular line that is causing the error is right below the module [bsCustomFileInput v1.3.2](https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-custom-file-input).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217045/discussion-between-emeka-okafor-and-moonrider).

Comment: Hmmm, I added the suggestion you made but I'm still getting that same error in app.js that prevents the page from loading.